# Vala: Can't get enter_notify_event to work correctly

Tags: hover, signals, vala

I'm not sure if I'm just misunderstanding something or what. I've been working on a podcast manager app, and one of the widgets is a EpisodeListItem, essentially it's intended to be a  subclass of Gtk.Box that holds the name of a podcast episode, and then play/download and delete buttons. I would like to make it so that the buttons only appear when the mouse is inside a given EpisodeListItem, and enter_notify_event and leave_notify_event seemed like they would achieve that for me. However I can't seem to get them to do anything.

Full code repo if more context is needed: https://github.com/leggettc18/leopod/tree/episode-downloads

Code for that file

```c
public class EpisodeListItem : Gtk.Box {
        // Data
        public Episode episode;

        // Widgets
        public Gtk.Box buttons_box;
        public Gtk.Button download_button;
        public Gtk.Button play_button;
        public Gtk.Button delete_button;
        public Gtk.Label title;

        // Constructors
        public EpisodeListItem (Episode episode) {
            info ("%s: %s", episode.title, episode.current_download_status.to_string ());
            add_events (
                Gdk.EventMask.ENTER_NOTIFY_MASK |
                Gdk.EventMask.LEAVE_NOTIFY_MASK
            );
            orientation = Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL;
            halign = Gtk.Align.FILL;
            this.episode = episode;
            title = new Gtk.Label (episode.title) {
                expand = true,
                halign = Gtk.Align.START
            };
            add (title);
            download_button = new Gtk.Button.from_icon_name (
                "browser-download-symbolic",
                Gtk.IconSize.BUTTON
            );
            play_button = new Gtk.Button.from_icon_name (
                "media-playback-start-symbolic",
                Gtk.IconSize.BUTTON
            );
            delete_button = new Gtk.Button.from_icon_name (
                "edit-delete-symbolic",
                Gtk.IconSize.BUTTON
            );

            buttons_box = new Gtk.Box (Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL, 5) {
                no_show_all = true
            };
            if (this.episode.current_download_status == DownloadStatus.NOT_DOWNLOADED) {
                buttons_box.pack_start (download_button);
            } else if (this.episode.current_download_status == DownloadStatus.DOWNLOADED){
                buttons_box.pack_start (play_button);
            }
            buttons_box.pack_end (delete_button);
            add (buttons_box);

            enter_notify_event.connect (() => {
                info ("Episode List Item entered");
                buttons_box.show ();
                return false;
            });

            leave_notify_event.connect (() => {
                buttons_box.hide ();
                return false;
            });
        }

        public override bool enter_notify_event (Gdk.EventCrossing event) {
            info ("EpisodeListItem entered");
            buttons_box.show ();
            return false;
        }
        
        public override bool leave_notify_event (Gdk.EventCrossing event) {
            buttons_box.hide ();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Can someone help me figure out where I'm going wrong/misunderstanding here? Or if there's a different way to handle mouse hover-type events?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out one way to get it to work. However, anyone else looking for help beware, as this implementation isn't working quite right for me for other reasons

First the Solution to getting enter and leave notify events to work. Turns out even if you apply the event masks Gtk.Box just can't respond to those events. The way I fixed this was to instead subclass the whole thing in Gtk.EventBox and then add the original Gtk.Box that was the widget itself as a child of the EventBox, like so.

```c
public class EpisodeListItem : Gtk.EventBox { //Subclass event box
//...
public Gtk.Box box; //Add a Gtk.Box as a property of the WidgetClass
//...
box = new Gtk.Box (Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL, 0);
add (box); //Add the Gtk.Box as a child of the EventBox
//...
box.add (title); //Add the title label and buttons_box, etc.
// as children of the Gtk.Box instead (repeat for the other child widgets)
```

Now, this works to achieve the desired effect of having the buttons appear and disappear based on mouse cursor hover state, however, it comes with the following problems.

- When the mouse hovers over the EventListItem in the UI, the widget kind of jumps as a height value of some sort changes. I've tried messing around with various height values and margins, but this "jump" always happens.
- More severely, when the mouse moves off of the widget **to the right specifically** for some reason, the whole thing freezes and pegs one of my CPU cores at 100%. I have no idea why this happens.

If anyone knows a better solution to the whole thing or knows a solution that avoids the weird freeze bug I described above please feel free to provide an answer.